# How can I read the local IP address into an .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am planning to use a single `.htaccess` file which may be deployed on multiple servers. In the process I am setting environment variables in the `.htaccess` file and there are a couple of cases where I would like to read the IP address into the settings. For instance, in one case I am setting an environment variable for the local database connection:

```
SetEnv DBL "mysql:dbname=oars;host=192.168.101.1;port=3306"
```

Then in PHP I would read the variable for use by the database interactions:

```
define('DBL', getenv('DBL'));
```

Since I am planning to deploy on multiple servers is there a way to get the IP address automagically rather than maintaining separate .htaccess files for each server?

Comment: If you want a local database connection for MySQL, why aren't you using `127.0.0.1`? For that matter, why aren't you using `localhost` and UNIX Sockets instead of TCP/IP?

Comment: Because of some of the peculiarities of our systems we cannot use the localhost or 127.0.0.1 addresses @Quentin

Comment: With `SetEnv DBL "mysql:dbname=oars;host=%{SERVER_ADDR};port=3306"` ?

Comment: That throws an error @Croises `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '%{SERVER_ADDR}' (0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Rule to set the Env variable:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DBL:mysql\:dbname=oars\;host=%{SERVER_ADDR}\;port=3306]

print getenv("DBL");
mysql:dbname=oars;host=1.2.3.4.5;port=3306
```

Comment: Oh wow! I had no idea you could set environment variables via a rewrite rule. Really eye opening and works perfectly.